# how can I get seperate the HTML in the_content(); output?

Tags: wp-query, the-content

I want to be able to seperate the first image form the post into a `<div>` tag and link it to the post page and be able to add html around the post text elements seprately.

Any help is greatly appreciated

This is what I have tried

```
                query_posts('posts_per_page=1&tag=food');
                while (have_posts()) : the_post();
                echo "<li class='homePost'>\n";
                    echo the_content();
                    echo '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">';
                    the_title();
                    echo '</a>'; 

                echo "</li>\n";
                endwhile;
```

Comment: I guess this is what the featured image is meant to replace...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at [this snippet](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/get-the-first-image-from-a-post/) from CSS-Tricks. It gets the first image from a post.